# Can't click on inputs at tablet/mobile widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue on a site I'm building for a friend which has got me a little stumped.  Full disclosure I picked up a theme on themeforest to get everything kickstarted since this was a freebie project.

The issue is that something is keeping me from selecting the one-line inputs at the smaller breakpoints.  The text area seems to work fine.

I set up codepen (http://codepen.io/misterhamm/pen/BoXZZy). Code below:

```
<form class="contact-comments m-top-50" id="contact-form">
   <div class="row">

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 form-group">
          <!-- Name -->
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class=" form-control" placeholder="Name *" maxlength="100" required="">
       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 form-group">
          <!-- Email -->
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class=" form-control" placeholder="Email *" maxlength="100" required="">
       </div>


       <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <!-- Phone -->
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class=" form-control" placeholder="Phone" maxlength="100">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <!-- Subject -->
          <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class=" form-control" placeholder="Company" maxlength="100">
       </div>

       <!-- Comment -->
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="cmnt-text form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Comments" maxlength="400"></textarea>
       </div>

       <!-- Send Button -->
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-dark-solid contact-submit">Send Message</button>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `col-xs-12` class to divs of comment and button that is.

You need to change following

```
<!-- Comment -->
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
...
...

<!-- Send Button -->
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
```

to this code

```
<!-- Comment -->
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">
...
... 

<!-- Send Button -->
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">
```

I don't know how this html and css actually works, but it worked after  making afore mentioned changes

Comment: Strange, I had to do the same thing to my bootstrap form. I had a specific input that just would not focus on when on xs screens. I added col-xs-* on all inputs beneath, and it worked. Anyone know why?

Comment: whoah cool, you are such a life saver to me, maybe because our "float" css is blocking, so i try to remove the float and apply this things, and it works fine for me